# what amazon s3 use for storage file ? , file storage or database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

what amazon s3 use for storage file ? file storage or database ?

is amazon direct storage file in storage file ?

or amazon storage file in some database like Dynamo db ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 is **object storage**. It is not a file system (eg C:\ drive). Rather, applications can place API calls to upload/download data.

Amazon S3 can also make objects available via HTTP/s without having to run a web server.

It is not a database (for that, use Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) or Amazon DynamoDB), however it could be used as a **large NoSQL database** since the object name is the `Key` and the contents of the object is the `Value`. However, DynamoDB is a much faster NoSQL database.

Typical use cases are:

- **File storage:** When applications want to store files locally (eg on the C:\ or D:\ drive)
- **File system** (eg Amazon Elastic File System (EFS)): A shared file system that can be simultaneously used between multiple computers, eg via NFS.
- **Database:** When applications want to store and retrieve data very quickly, or write complex SQL queries
- **Object storage:** When data storage is off-loaded to a central server/service.

For more information, see: [Cloudian: Object Storage vs. File Storage: What's the Difference?](https://cloudian.com/blog/object-storage-vs-file-storage/)

Comment: first thank you john for reply ,but what happen when i we add some file on amazon or what happen with that file ?. amazon add file in file system or amazon add as stream in database ?

Comment: I presume you are talking about Amazon S3? When an object is uploaded to S3, it is stored in the bucket and is then available for access. As to "how" it is stored in S3, that is an implementation detail that is handled by AWS and is neither revealed nor relevant for usage. You could actually think of S3 as a very large NoSQL database, with the "Name" being the name of the object and the "Value" being the contents of the object. But that isn't necessarily how it is stored.